# asp.net generate file during buil without reference to Project

Tags: asp.net, reference, compilation, namespaces, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing an `Web Api Application`. I have the coded separated in differents Projects.

The first Project is the `main` projects. It is a `Web Api project`. IT is the stared project.

The Second project is a `Class` project. In this project I create a `.config` file in `/debug folder` when the application is build..

```html
 private static log4net.ILog log;
        public LoggingService()
        {
            var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "bin\\" + "log4net.config";
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(path));
         }
```

I have some others Class projects where I have logic issues.

The last Project is where i handle de `Dependency Resolution`. I have a reference to all projects.

The problem I have is that, in order to generate a .config file during building, I have to have a reference to this project in the main Project.

My idea is to isolated it, and having a reference to it do not allow me to do it.

My question is, if it is possible to generate a file from a Project during building without having a reference to it in main Project.

I did what   `MethodMan` told me and assign the same namespace to both projects.

The Project that generate config file has the same namespace that Web Api Project has. The problem I have is the file is not generated when `Dependency Resolution` is executed.

In Global.asax I have

```html
private void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
               kernel.Load(new DependencyResolution.RepositoryModule());
        }
```

and in Dependency Resolution Project I have

```html
 public override void Load()
        {
            BindRepositoriesByConvention(Kernel);
        }

       
        private static void BindRepositoriesByConvention(IKernel kernel)
        {
           
            kernel.Bind<Interface1>().To<Service1>().InSingletonScope();
            kernel.Bind<Interface2>().To<Service2>().InSingletonScope();
        }
```

Because of this execution, .config file, is not generated.

Thanks

Comment: will all of these projects reside inside of a single solution..? if so then lookup how to use `namespace`

Comment: Yes, is the same solution. I can put in the same namespace? Thanks